# Regular Expression Extractor Jmeter - I want to send email for 404 response codes

Tags: regex, jmeter, http-response-codes, extractor

I am writing a test case which will hit a URLs and send email if response code is 404. Request is going well and Response also coming but I am stuck at Regular Expression Extractor.[Sample Request Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izOp4.png)[image: Email Code is here]

[![Sample Result for HTTP Request][Extractor Page]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2hiq.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Amend your **Regular Expression** to be `\d+`
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) after the "Landing Page Verification" request and use `"${responsemsg}" == "404"` as the condition
3. Make SMTP Request sampler a child of the If Controller

Example [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) snapshot

[image: JMeter Regex Test Plan]

Comment: Great. Thanks. Can you elaborate \d+ in simple words. Also this script sending email for each 404 error. Can I send only one email for all 404 errors. Advance Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the regular expression to **(\d+)** and template to **$1$** and match no. to **1**. see [using regex with jmeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) and [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) from jmeter user manual for more information.