# jmeter send email assertion

Tags: email, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and am looking for a way to send emails out for every failed assertion.

Test Structure:

1. Thread Group:

   - Transaction Controller:

     - Http Request:
     - Http Request:
     - Http Request:
2. Thread Group:

   - Transaction Controller:

     - Http Request:
     - Http Request:
     - Http Request:

Each Http request contains a response assertion. I would like to capture and send one email that contains all of the failed assertions within a transaction controller.  Is there a way to do this?  I tried using adding a SMTP Sampler within a thread group with a child Bean PreProcessor that contains this code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;


try {
        AssertionResult[] results = prev.getAssertionResults();
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    for (AssertionResult result : results) {
        body.append(result.getName());
        body.append(result.getFailureMessage());
        body.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    vars.put("body", body.toString());
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

When i do this it will only send an email of the last failed assertion instead of all failed assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a **global** [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) (it is much better to use [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) rather than Beanshell, see [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area (it is basically your code but amended to read previous samplers results from the `${body}` variable and append new results to them

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

   try {
       AssertionResult[] results = prev.getAssertionResults();

       StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
       String previousBody = vars.get("body");
       if (previousBody != null) {
           body.append(previousBody);
       }
       for (AssertionResult result : results) {
           body.append(result.getName());
           body.append(result.getFailureMessage());
           body.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
       }
       vars.put("body", body.toString());
   } catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Error in Groovy", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

We have a test that prints out request body information to the console on failure.  This is added to each sampler individually and works quite nicely.  You could update this code send a failure message instead of printing to the console.

```
//Loop through assertions and check for failed
for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
     if (results[i].isFailure() || results[i].isError()){
         failed_assertion = true;
         System.out.println("\n********** Request Body ***************\n"+ctx.getCurrentSampler().getUrl().getPath()+ctx.getCurrentSampler().getQueryString()+'\n'+ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()+"\n");
    System.out.println("************ ERROR DETECTED ***********\n"+prev.getResponseDataAsString()+"\n****************************************\n");
    break;
   }
}
```

If that doesn't work you could construct an IF block on each sampler.  Similar to what they're doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845778/regular-expression-extractor-jmeter-i-want-to-send-email-for-404-response-code).